# Manage magento inventory from differents ERP systems

Tags: php, magento-1.9, erp

Scenario:

> We have a Magento 1.9 store already in production with a product register integrated with the store's internal system (InfoxA), which automatically manages inventory, price, entry and exit.
>
> The customer has opened a new store, in the same segment, and wants to join the two stores in the Magento system.
>
> However, he want the products in the new store to be managed by another internal system (InfoxB).
>
> Ex. When user inserts in the cart Product A + Product B the system automatically downloads in their respective inventory systems.

Demand:

```
Products with SKU = "SD" = managed by ERP Infox 1
Products with SKU = "SL" = managed by ERP Infox 2
```

Summing up:

How to make a system in magento 1.9 manage to have certain products managed by one ERP and others by another ERP?

Solutions:

- Multistores?
- Multiviews?
- Marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure **all product SKUs are unique** between ERPs.
You can have the same SKU in both ERPs, but then you will have to decide where to invoice the item from.

Second, please **describe the integration method** or protocol between ERP and Magento webstore.
If you are using a Magento extension to get product and inventory data from ERP you could clone the extension with a different namespace (including class names, db table names, Magento system variables names, etc.) and then configure it for the second ERP (asuming both ERPs have a similar platform, version, etc.). You will have to repeat this process every time you make an update to the original extension. However, if your extension also sends orders from webstore back to ERP for invoicing you will have a hard time splitting items between ERP stores.

Third, having separate store views for each ERP inventory will prevent you from displaying all the products in one place. Store views usually help with localization and/or custom page layouts. Having separate stores on your Magento installation should work, but you will need to make all the neccessary system configurations and you will still not be able to display all products in one page.

Fourth, ordering items from different ERPs will most likely break any shopping cart price rules you might need to implemnent later on. For instance, if you discount 10% for a purchase above $100 you then have to decide which ERP makes the discount or how do you split it between both of them.

---